# What are the pros and cons of Unirest over RestAssured for API testing?

Tags: rest-assured, web-api-testing, unirest

I have used rest assured before and not aware of unirest much. Does anyone used both and can tell me which one is better to automate rest APIs

Answer (score 1):

Based on the below mentioned Pros and Cons, I know. Rest-Assured is best to test and automate Rest API.

**Pros**

**Unirest**

1. Support Available in 8 languages like Node, Ruby, Java, Python, Objective C etc.
2. Both syncronous and asynchronous (non-blocking) requests.

**Rest Assured**

1. DSL
2. Inbuilt library of Assertions, Matchers and Extractors.
3. Easy integration with TestNG/JUnit.
4. Follow BDD/Gherkin for readable behaviour driven test cases.
5. Minimal Documentation.
6. Designed and Built for API Automation Testing.

**Cons**

**Unirest**

1. No in-built library for Matchers/ Extractors / Assertions.
2. Simple HTTP Client Library.

**RestAssured**

1. Supports only Java Language.